# HTTP request is not breaking up the path from querystring in some requests

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a weird problem which don't know how to solve.

The usual behavior for .NET is if you have a URL like: `/action?id=abc&=type=3`
the server variable are like:

```
URL: /action  
PATH_INFO: /action
QUERY_STRING: id=abc&=type=3
```

But here comes the weird behavior: when the request comes from mediapartners-google, the server variables don't split the URL at the question mark and are:

```
URL: /action?id=abc&=type=3   
PATH_INFO: /action?id=abc&=type=3   
QUERY_STRING:
```

So the routing engine is trying to find an action name called `action?id=abc&=type=3` and it doesn't find it, providing a 404 error.

Does anyone knows why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

For MVC when the routing engine has matched a route the rest gets stuffed into the optional parameter. It quite possible to have a route match before it reaches the question mark. Its looks like you need another route to handle this case. Also remember you need your routes in order of strongest to weakest as they are processed by the first route that matches.

Comment: the route works well when called from a browser, it's when called from  mediapartners-google when it doesn't work. The server variables are populated before the mvc framework comes to action.

Comment: I don't know of any way it would even be possible to treat a URL accessed from mediapartners-google different to a URL accessed via the browser. A URL is a URL is a URL. Therefore the logical assumption is that the URL is subtly different in some way. I would log the absolute URLs in global.asax.Application_BeginRequest and see what you get. There must be something different in the request for this to be happening...